# what is the alternative way to check for null with out using is null operator in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I had written an stored procedure where selecting from one table(some columns have null data) and inserting into other table with out duplicates.

part of my stored procedure code:

```
 LOOP
   BEGIN
     SELECT ID
       INTO ROWCOUNT
   FROM TBL_EMPLOYEE
 WHERE 

     NAME      = TEMPTABLE.NAME
  AND AGE           =TEMPTABLE.AGE

EXCEPTION
WHEN no_data_found THEN
  ROWCOUNT := 0;
END;
IF ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
  INSERT INTO TARGET TABLE ......
```

In the above piece of code there is null data for some columns(eg: TEMPTABLE.AGE  etc).
when there is null value it is throwing no_data_found exception and it is inserting the data. we tried alternatively by putting nvl function which is taking more time.

```
LOOP
BEGIN
  SELECT ID
  INTO ROWCOUNT
  FROM TBL_EMPLOYEE
 WHERE 

     nvl(NAME,0000)      = nvl(TEMPTABLE.NAME,0000)
  AND nvl(AGE,0000)           =nvl(TEMPTABLE.AGE,0000)

EXCEPTION
WHEN no_data_found THEN
  ROWCOUNT := 0;
END;
IF ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
  INSERT INTO TARGET TABLE ......
```

Can any one suggest any alternative how to do null check with equals to operator.
I have tried it with LIKE as well but it did not work.

Comment: why u do not want to use is null check?

Comment: I want to use is null but when there is no data it is coming as null value. but when there is data, it should check with "=". Correct me if wrong.

Comment: I tried using LIKE also but it is not working to check null. Any Idea?

Comment: why you're not using nvl all the time? without checking for the exception, or maybe i dont understand youre question

Comment: Hi @Dom84, I have tried it giving all the time, but, it is hitting the performance. I have to process more than 20k records like this and it is failing/timeout in 2k records itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to do this:

```
NAME = VALUE {in case of Some Value}
```

and

```
NAME IS NULL {in case the value is null}
```

ORACLE doesn't handles it by its own. I think this is a logical condition and this should be handled logically. Let me know if I have answered/understood you correctly?

Comment: thanks finally I handled with query string inside stored procedure by checking if and else blocks.

Answer (score 1):

You are going about the check in the wrong way. Eliminate both the `ROWCOUNT` variable and the loop altogether and use `NOT EXISTS()`:

```
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TARGET_TABLE
  SELECT .....
  FROM DUAL 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM TBL_EMPLOYEE
    WHERE nvl(NAME,0000) = nvl(TEMPTABLE.NAME,0000)
    AND nvl(AGE,0000) = nvl(TEMPTABLE.AGE,0000);
END
```

And your condition may have a bug: If your intention is to treat two nulls as "equal", change the condition to:

```
WHERE (NAME = TEMPTABLE.NAME OR NVL(NAME, TEMPTABLE.NAME) IS NULL)
AND (AGE = TEMPTABLE.AGE OR NVL(AGE, TEMPTABLE.AGE) IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
nvl(NAME,0000) = nvl(TEMPTABLE.NAME,0000)
```

with

```
(NAME is NULL and TEMPTABLE.NAME is null or NAME = TEMPTABLE.NAME)
```

Comment: Sorry! No luck :( Got this error :ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

Comment: @Madhu sudhan Reddy Did you put parentheses? Because I gave you almost equivalent version of your condition (your condition will also return true if the name is null and temptable.name = 0)

Comment: @MadhusudhanReddy Error message is self descriptive. It is supposed to retrieve only one row. You want a `count(ID)` ?

Comment: @Multisync : i used exactly the same what you mentioned above.but still not working.

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar : yes i require only one row. but count function is taking more time if there are more records.

Answer (score 0):

Try to explain in the simplest terms what you want to accomplish. You give a confusing set of requirements, and are throwing in some code that puts us probably on the wrong track anyhow. Likely what you need can be done in one statement, without a loop. Some Attempts:

Remove duplicates by some key columns [name,age] distinguished by the value of another.

```
INSERT INTO target (name,age,other_value1,other_value2)
SELECT
  name, age,other_value1,other_value2
FROM (
  SELECT
    name,
    age,
    other_value1,
    other_value2,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name,age ORDER BY other_value1) rn
  FROM source
  ) WHERE rn = 1
```

The distinguishing column, could be a timestamp of when the data was entered, for which you could use something like `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name,age ORDER BY time_entered DESC) rn` to keep the most recent record.

Remove duplicates based on all columns

```
INSERT INTO target (name,age,other_value1,other_value2)
SELECT
  name, age,other_value1,other_value2
FROM source
GROUP BY name,age,other_value1,other_value2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN
  SELECT ID
  INTO ROWCOUNT
  FROM TBL_EMPLOYEE
 WHERE decode(NAME,TEMPTABLE.NAME,1)=1
   AND decode(AGE,TEMPTABLE.AGE,1)=1
EXCEPTION
WHEN no_data_found THEN
  ROWCOUNT := 0;
END;
```

And it works with any simple datatype - number varchar2, date and etc.

Comment: It is working fine for less number of rows eg: <1000 . If more than 1000 it is really taking more time. Is there any other alternative way which will not hit performance.

Comment: It depends... Obviously it does not use your b*tree indexes and uses full table scan. You might need consider functional indexes something like this: created index indx1 on tnl_employee on(nvl(NAME, '{null}')); And then use in query following expression: nvl(name, '{name}') = nvl(temptable.name, '{null}') Alternatively you can consider bitmap indexes but bear in mind about locks...

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

SELECT Name, Age FROM TBL_EMPLOYEE WHERE 
NAME = 'yourName' AND
(  (AGE = yourAge) OR (AGE IS NULL AND yourAge is NULL)  )

Here NAME and AGE are table column names.
'yourName' and 'yourAge' are runtime values passed.

Let me know if it don't work for you.